# Unable to retrieve values from buttons press in Android Calculator App

Tags: android, android-activity

Currently trying to get my simple Android Calculator App working. When I try to run on an emulator I get:
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

I'm also having an issue returning the result to the textview. I've tried tvResult.setText(result); but it isn't allowing me to pass in a float to the text.

My Java:

```
package com.example.justin.calculator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import javax.xml.transform.Result;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    EditText digit1;
    EditText digit2;
    TextView tvResult;

    Button nine, eight, seven, six, five, four, three, two, one, zero, decimal, plus, minus, divide, multiply, equals;
    String s = "0";

    char enterDigit = ' ';
    String enterOperation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //button elements
        nine = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
        eight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
        seven = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
        six = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
        five = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        four = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        three = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        zero = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button0);
        decimal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttondecimal);
        plus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonadd);
        minus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonminus);
        divide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttondivide);
        multiply = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonmultiply);
        equals = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonequals);
        tvResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResult);

        //set listeners
        nine.setOnClickListener(this);
        eight.setOnClickListener(this);
        seven.setOnClickListener(this);
        six.setOnClickListener(this);
        five.setOnClickListener(this);
        four.setOnClickListener(this);
        three.setOnClickListener(this);
        two.setOnClickListener(this);
        one.setOnClickListener(this);
        decimal.setOnClickListener(this);
        plus.setOnClickListener(this);
        minus.setOnClickListener(this);
        divide.setOnClickListener(this);
        multiply.setOnClickListener(this);
        equals.setOnClickListener(this);
        tvResult.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        float num1 = 0;
        float num2 = 0;
        float result = 0;

        num1 = Float.parseFloat(digit1.getText().toString());
        num2 = Float.parseFloat(digit2.getText().toString());

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.buttonadd:
                enterOperation = "+";
                result = num1 + num2;
                break;
            case R.id.buttonminus:
                enterOperation = "-";
                result = num1 - num2;
                break;
            case R.id.buttonmultiply:
                enterOperation = "*";
                result = num1 * num2;
                break;
            case R.id.buttondivide:
                enterOperation = "/";
                result = num1 / num2;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }


    }
}
```

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvResult"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="0"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textSize="50sp"/>"

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="enterDigit">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="7"
            android:onClick="enterDigit"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="8"
            android:onClick="enterDigit"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="9"
            android:onClick="enterDigit"/>"


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttondivide"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="/"
            android:onClick="enterOperation"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="4"
            android:onClick="enterDigit"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="5"
            android:onClick="enterDigit"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="6"
            android:onClick="enterDigit"/>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonmultiply"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="*"
            android:onClick="enterOperation"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="1"
            android:onClick="enterDigit"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="2"
            android:onClick="enterDigit"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="3"
            android:onClick="enterDigit"/>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonminus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="-"
            android:onClick="enterOperation"/>


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="0"
            android:onClick="enterDigit"/>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttondecimal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="." />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonequals"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="="
            android:onClick="calculate"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonadd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="+"
            android:onClick="enterOperation"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your EditText widgets do not exist in your xml. They need to be added in your main LinearLayout somewhere. Then, in your onCreate() method, you need to set them up via the findViewById(R.id.digit1)... Also, get rid of the onClick attribute in the LinearLayout; because your linearLayout is not clickable, it is useless.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/digit1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/digit2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvResult"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="0"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textSize="50sp"/>"

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="7"
            android:onClick="enterDigit"/>

 ...
```

then, in your activity...

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle sIS){
    super.onCreate(sIS);
    digit1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.digit1);
    digit2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.digit2);

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to init your EditText (digit1 and digit1) firstlg as your buttons do, if not it will lead to NullPointException just like your proplem